# Search files based on the date modified entered by user in console application VB.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, date, console-application

i been given a assignment to create one console application using VB.NET. The assignment will able to open the file that based on the date modified entered by user. can anyone help me to solve my problem. I'm new in vb.net and most of the tutorial are using C# . together i put the latest code i has already done but still if i put the date modified the error file will display .

Thank you in advance

```
Imports System.IO

Module Module3
    Sub Main()
        While True

            ' Read value.

            Dim s As DateTime = Console.ReadLine()

            ' Test the value.
            If s = File.GetLastWriteTime("path") Then

                Dim p As New Process()
                p.StartInfo = New ProcessStartInfo("notepad.exe", "path")
                p.Start()

            Else

                Dim p As New Process()
                p.StartInfo = New ProcessStartInfo("notepad.exe", "path2")
                p.Start()

            End If

            ' Write the value.
            Console.WriteLine("You typed " + s)

        End While
    End Sub
End Module
```

Comment: What error are you getting, and on which line?

Comment: If you want us to help, you should provide us with all the information necessary for us to help you.  You mentioned an error.  Don't you think it's important to tell us what the error is?  At the top of your code file add `Option Strict On` or go into your project properties and turn on Option Strict.  `Console.ReadLine` returns a `String` but you are storing the result into a `DateTime` variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the code snippet you are not searching for a file you are setting the time last modified which isn't what you want to do.

you will need to search through each file until you find the date modified information which is inputted by the user:-

```
dim s as datetime = console.readline()

'Target Directory
Dim directory = "C:\Users\Peter\Desktop\TestFolder\"


For Each filename As String In IO.Directory.GetFiles(directory, "*", IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    Dim fName As String = IO.Path.GetExtension(filename)
    dim datemod as string = File.GetLastWriteTime(directory & fname)

        If s = datemod Then
            Dim p As New Process()
            p.StartInfo = New ProcessStartInfo("notepad.exe", directory & fname)
            p.Start()
        Else
            'do something else
        endif
next
```

things that you will need to add are, what to do when it doesn't find a file with that variable.

hope this gets you a little further.