# Deleting folders based on csv

Tags: vb.net

I am currently trying to solve a problem using VB but have hit a brick wall. I am not much of a coder and as usual understand the basics but the task is too advanced for me at this stage.

Essentially I would like to delete a folder (all folders and files contained) that exists in two specific locations based on the login name that exists within a csv taken from AD (produced each day).

The current script disables the user account after 90 days, removes some groups and moves the user account to a disabled OU. I need it to also delete their user profile and redirected folders which will match their login name contained in the CSV.

I've so far assembled the below:

```
'Open up the text file
Dim oFSO, oTS
Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set oTS = oFSO.OpenTextFile("c:\scripts\GmailDisabled.csv

'Assumes the CSV files first row will be the column names and they will be User Name, Email Address, Date Account Expired, Original OU (currently missing login name)

'Creates the variables
Dim sLoginName

'Skip the first line in the code
Dim sLine, sData
sLine - oTS.ReadLine

'Go through file one line at a time
Do Until oTS.AtEndOfStream

'Get the user information from this row
sLoginName - sData(0)
```

The CSV has the following information:

User Name,Login Name,Email Address,Date Account Expired,Original OU

The paths are:

```
\\netapp01fs\profiles\%username%

\\rukredir\%username%
```

I think Id have more luck in Powershell but it really needs to be VB. It would also be helpful to update a CSV each time something is deleted.

Thank you for having a look and any help you can provide
Dan

Comment: Can you show us a sample csv? This doesn't seem to be vb.net but vb6.

Comment: a line from a csv can be read easily like this dim csvValues() as string = sline.split(","). Give me 30 minutes and when I come back I'll give you an answer

Comment: also you can look at my loop in directories to find specific files here:- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42826832/search-files-based-on-the-date-modified-entered-by-user-in-console-application-v/42832771#42832771

Comment: That code is not VB.Net.  Are you using VB.Net or just VBScript or VBA?

Answer (score 0):

```
    'Assumes the CSV files first row will be the column names and they will be User Name, Email Address, Date Account Expired, Original OU (currently missing login name)
```

"test.csv"
Login Name, User Name, Email Address,Date Account Expired,Original OU
Daniel.Gange,Daniel Gange,Daniel.Gange@test.co.uk,09/08/2017,"CN=Daniel Gange,OU=Test,OU=Test,DC=Test,DC=co,DC=uk"

```
    Using sr As StreamReader = File.OpenText("c:\scripts\GmailDisabled.csv")
        sr.ReadLine() 'read the first line you said to skip
        Do
            Dim xData As String = sr.ReadLine()  'read one line at the time
            Dim csvValue() As String = xData.Split(",") ' split at every comma (csv file)
            ' the first value always has index 0 which is username
            Dim sUserName As String = csvValue(0)
            Dim PathToDelete1 As String = String.Format("\\netapp01fs\profiles\{0}", sUserName)
            Dim PathToDelete2 As String = String.Format("\\rukredir\\{0}", sUserName)
            MsgBox(PathToDelete1)
            MsgBox(PathToDelete2)
        Loop Until sr.EndOfStream = True 'loop until the end of file
        sr.Close() 'close the csv
    End Using
```

If the code works the way you want then use this one to actually delete your folders. Never erase files/folders when testing something that deletes data. You might end up deleting something you don't want to delete.

```
'Assumes the CSV files first row will be the column names and they will be User Name, Email Address, Date Account Expired, Original OU (currently missing login name)
Using sr As StreamReader = File.OpenText("c:\scripts\GmailDisabled.csv")
    sr.ReadLine() 'read the first line you said to skip
    Do
        Dim xData As String = sr.ReadLine()  'read one line at the time
        Dim csvValue() As String = xData.Split(",") ' split at every comma (csv file)
        ' the first value always has index 0 which is username
        Dim sUserName As String = csvValue(0)
        Dim PathToDelete1 As String = String.Format("\\netapp01fs\profiles\{0}", sUserName)
        Dim PathToDelete2 As String = String.Format("\\rukredir\\{0}", sUserName)
        Directory.Delete(PathToDelete1, True) ' set recursive to True to delete files and sub folders
        Directory.Delete(PathToDelete2, True) ' set recursive to True to delete files and sub folders
        'MsgBox(PathToDelete1)
        'MsgBox(PathToDelete2)
    Loop Until sr.EndOfStream = True 'loop until the end of file
    sr.Close() 'close the csv
End Using
```

Shorter version

```
    'Assumes the CSV files first row will be the column names and they will be User Name, Email Address, Date Account Expired, Original OU (currently missing login name)
    Using sr As StreamReader = File.OpenText("c:\scripts\GmailDisabled.csv")
        sr.ReadLine() 'read the first line you said to skip
        Do
            Dim xData As String = sr.ReadLine()  'read one line at the time
            ' the first value always has index 0 which is username
            Directory.Delete(String.Format("\\netapp01fs\profiles\{0}", xData.Split(",")(0)), True) ' set recursive to True to delete files and sub folders
            Directory.Delete(String.Format("\\rukredir\\{0}", xData.Split(",")(0)), True) ' set recursive to True to delete files and sub folders
        Loop Until sr.EndOfStream = True 'loop until the end of file
        sr.Close() 'close the csv
    End Using
```

Comment: John Smith,John.Smith@dfdsgdsgsdgsdfdsf,08/08/2017,"CN=John Smith,OU=Test,OU=Test,DC=Test,DC=co,DC=uk"

Comment: User Name,Email Address,Date Account Expired,Original OU

Comment: Currently the export doesn't include the login name, I was going to add this later.

Comment: Thanks for all the replies, Chillzy ill do some testing and let you know.

Comment: @DanielGange You could query your DC and streamline your process

Comment: Hi, I'm likely doing something wrong here but I am getting Error: Expected end of statement - 800A0401 - Line 2 - Char 14.

I've changed the destinations to reflect a local test:

The csv looks like the below:

Login Name, User Name, Email Address,Date Account Expired,Original OU
Daniel.Gange,Daniel Gange,Daniel.Gange@test.co.uk,09/08/2017,"CN=Daniel Gange,OU=Test,OU=Test,DC=Test,DC=co,DC=uk"

Thanks again
Dan

Comment: Using sr As StreamReader = File.OpenText("c:\users\daniel.gange\documents\GmailDisabled.csv")
        sr.ReadLine() 'read the first line you said to skip
        Do
            Dim xData As String = sr.ReadLine()  'read one line at the time
            ' the first value always has index 0 which is username
            Directory.Delete(String.Format("\\c:\users\daniel.gange\desktop\{0}", xData.Split(",")(0)), True) ' set recursive to True to delete files and sub folders

Comment: Directory.Delete(String.Format("\\c:\users\daniel.gange\documents\{0}", xData.Split(",")(0)), True) ' set recursive to True to delete files and sub folders
        Loop Until sr.EndOfStream = True 'loop until the end of file
        sr.Close() 'close the csv
    End Using

Comment: @DanielGange I've use the test lines you included in your comment. Works has expected. Create a sub and only put the code I supplied and try it

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance, I take it you mean enclose the code in sub name & end sub. If so then I get the same issue, strange..

Comment: Im wondering whether this is the problem.

In VBScript everything (variables, function return values, etc.) is a Variant (i.e. pretty much a duck, like in JavaScript). It is illegal to declare an explicit type when declaring a variable. The As keyword is illegal!